# Learning Algorithms/Neural networks books?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, neural-networks, references, bioinformatics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Machine learning cookbook / reference card / cheatsheet?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet)
>   [Machine learning self-learning book?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20040/machine-learning-self-learning-book)

What are some good theoretical and practical machine learning algorithms books? I am particularly looking for a book that explains the most important and prominent machine learning algorithms being used today. Also is there a good book for learning basic neural networks? I am looking for both theory and application so suggestions on either is good.

I am only a beginner in the field, so the easier to understand the book is the better!

Comment: There are several questions on this topic already on CV. You should look at those, & then, if there is something specific that you want to know that isn't there already, update your question w/ that more specific info. In the interim, this Q should be closed as a duplicate. Here are some links: [how-to-get-started-with-neural-networks](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36247/), [a-good-machine-learning-book](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35535/), & [machine-learning-self-learning-book](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20040/).

Comment: I was looking specifically for a book that can explain the different Learning Algorithms for machine learning (not a general overview of machine learning), I'm not sure if such a book exists but it's worth a shot to ask.

Comment: @user1676226 well, every good about machine learning should explain the learning algorithms (with more or less coverage of all). I think you refer to a cheatsheet, see this question [Machine learning cookbook / reference card / cheatsheet?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12386/machine-learning-cookbook-reference-card-cheatsheet) or [What are the “hot algorithms” for machine learning?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17227/what-are-the-hot-algorithms-for-machine-learning)

Comment: maybe also of interest [Can you recommend a book to read before Elements of Statistical Learning?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18973/can-you-recommend-a-book-to-read-before-elements-of-statistical-learning)

Answer (score 3):

If you are new to Machine Learning, I strongly recommend that you at watch the videos that are a part of Professor Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera.org.  The URL is for the currently running class is https://class.coursera.org/ml-2012-002/class/index

Professor Ng's lectures for his Stanford Machine Learning course are also on iTunes University.

Answer (score 2):

Following post of @HeatfanJohn on coursera website https://www.coursera.org/ you can also find a few courses on algorithms and NN just running or starting very soon.

Another good source is udacity.com with similar idea.

If you want some more theoretical knowledge in NN you can find http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC3EA65335EAC29EE8 usefull.